# How to sync a Git Repository Branches with FTP?

Tags: git, github, ftp

Is there any way possible to sync git master and develop branch with different ftp servers so that i can see the develop branch changes on my stage server and when I merge the code with master branch so changes will done on live server ??

I just have begin working with git and have basic knowledge so really looking forward to your assistance.

Comment: do you want to map a web server's content to a given branch in git? where does github come into play here?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're looking for a build system. There are a few routes you can take.

[FTPloy](https://ftploy.com/) is building a business out of exactly what you're looking for. Push to GitHub, code is uploaded to FTP.

[TravisCI](https://travis-ci.com/) is a well known general build system. You can use it to [deploy via FTP](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/), and it allows plenty of configuration on a per-branch basis, though the configuration has a medium-steep learning curve.

[git-ftp](https://git-ftp.github.io/git-ftp/) syncs a Git repo to an FTP server, which should let you easily build your own scripts to do what you like.

Comment: `git-ftp` was quite easy to use. You first configure ftp server and user/password and then after usual git commit / push, `git ftp push` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Setup builds in any CI tool like Jenkins to for each branch that you want to publish. Use rsync (if allowed) or ftp/sftp command as a build step to publish the changes to desired remote servers. Using rsync is better option as it is faster with updates.

Having this in a CI tool like Jenkins will ensure that you will retain build history of the FTP updates you do in CI itself so you are aware of what has been going on

Incase you have your repositories in github, stash or gitlab, disable polling from CI tool and use webhooks to notify the CI tool you use for every push applied on the desired branches. This ensures that you don't perform unnecessary polling and job runs from the CI tool when there are no changes in GIT repository. It also ensures that the refresh will be triggered immediately as the job will be started by your git repository when it receives the change.